# Playing movieclip in parts (as2 flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, playback, movieclip

I have got an timeline with in it an movieclip of 60 frames total.

Those 60 frames can be divided into groups 20 frames which in total form a loop of a circulair motion.

Also in have got 2 buttons. A forward button and a backward button.

How can i make the buttons make the button play 20 frames of the movieclip and then stop? Next click, next 20 frames, Next click, next 20 frames. And offcourse also the other way around for the backward button.

I am quite new to ActionScript and find it difficult to google what i need!

Hope you guys can help me out on this one. It seems to be an simple task...

Comment: I did already find a workaround... but if anyone has a "valid" solution i'll be happy to hear it!

Comment: Stick the groups into individual movie clips?

Answer (score 0):

```
var frame = 1;
backwardBtn.onRelease = function(){
    if(frame != 1){
        frame -= 1;
    }
}

forwardBtn.onRelease = function(){
    if(frame != 60){
        frame += 1;
    }
}

mc.onEnterFrame = function(){
    gotoAndStop(frame);
}
```